# Cannot call the PayPal Sync API due to Authorization Failure

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to use the relatively new [PayPal Sync API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/) to download my PayPal transactions.  I'm following [the Sync API guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/sync/).  I started by logging into the PayPal Developer Dashboard [My Apps & Credentials page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/), scrolling to the **REST API apps** section, creating an app, clicking on it, and enabling **Transaction Search** for both the Sandbox and Live accounts.

I then used the Sandbox account's Client ID and Secret to generate an Access Token.  I confirmed that the Client ID and Secret are correct and active.  My cURL command is below (note that I'm using cURL on Windows 10):

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token ^
   -H "Accept: application/json" ^
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" ^
   -u "<my-client-id>:<my-secret>" ^
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I received a response similar to the following (I added the formatting):

```
{
  "scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read 
           https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* 
           https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks 
           openid",
  "nonce":"2018-04-04T02:20:02Z...",
  "access_token":"<my-access-token>",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "app_id":"<my-app-id>",
  "expires_in":32400
}
```

I then took the Access Token and copied it into [the sample command](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/sync/#list-transactions) on the Sync API guide page.  Here is the command I ran:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?transaction_id=5TY05013RG002845M&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1 ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <my-access-token>"
```

I received the following error response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
...
< Content-Length: 244
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
<
{
  "name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
  "message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.",
  "links":[{
    "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error",
    "rel":"information_link"
  }]
}
```

I tried many things to correct this error, including:

1. Adding a "Accept: application/json" and "Accept-Language: en_US" header to the command.
2. Creating a new Secret and generating a new Access Token.
3. Creating a new App with a new Client ID & Secret and generating a new Access Token.
4. Disabling **Transaction Search**, re-enabling it, and sending the command again.
5. Trying in the Live account.

Each of these attempts produced the same result.  I noted that in the scope section of the access token response that it doesn't include a path similar to the stated path for the Sync API (/v1/reporting/transactions).  However, that's just an observation, and I'm not sure if that is relevant.

I read through the entire Sync API guides and documentation about five times, and I searched Google and StackOverflow pretty thoroughly.  I'm seeing [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429030/filter-paypal-transactions-received-payments-using-paypal-sync-api) that some people are getting past the initial connection to Sync API, so I'm fairly certain this API works.

**Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?**  Could it just be that I need to wait a day or two for their systems to catch up?  PayPal's Developer documentation is not very user-friendly, and their Developer Dashboard is extremely glitchy.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. Putting double quotes around the URL solved it for me. The other API endpoints worked (authentication, authorizations/xyz) because they didn't have any special URL characters in them. In the transaction search, the query string delimiters were being parsed by Bash.

Your curl lines above become:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?transaction_id=5TY05013RG002845M&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <my-access-token>"
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: The quotation marks solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: You're a genius.  Why didn't they put this in the docs ?!  For me it was adding page_size=xx that broke the request without quotes. I made a change to your example, the opening quote should be in front of https:

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this error may be caused by either cURL or the way I'm using it.  On a hunch, I used [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) to execute this sample request, and the request was successful (HTTP 200).  I then tried another request where I searched for all transactions in a given date range, and that was also successful.  I'm going to mark the question answered.

Comment: i am facing the same issue with node. how did u resolve this issue?